# emacs org-mode tree to list

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I'm looking for a concise way to read a specific tree (including subtrees) into a list.

Say I've got:

```
* Branch
** Small branch
** Another small branch
*** Leaves
* Flowers
```

The function should be able to search by regular expression and copy the subtree (e.g. search for Branch) to a list like:

```
'(("Small branch") ("Another small branch" ("Leaves")))
```

Comment: You should expand on what exactly you mean by 'list' - I can think of several ways to interpret this, the most obvious among them being `'(("Branch" ("Small branch") ("Another small branch" ("Leaves"))) ("Flowers"))`

Comment: Yip, that's what I meant. Thanks Sean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
(defun org-list-siblings ()
  "List siblings in current buffer starting at point.
Note, you can always (goto-char (point-min)) to collect all siblings."
  (interactive)
  (let (ret)
    (unless (org-at-heading-p)
      (org-forward-heading-same-level nil t))
    (while (progn
         (setq ret (cons (append (list (substring-no-properties (org-get-heading)))
                       (save-excursion
                         (when (org-goto-first-child)
                           (org-list-siblings))))
                 ret))
         (org-goto-sibling)))
      (nreverse ret)))
```

If you do not need the full tree but a sub-tree put point on the first of its children headings.
That is methodical since the top-level headings are interpreted as the first children. There is no common root.